Why can generalized forces be derived from generalized potentials? Doesn't this confuse their relation to kinetic energy?
In Wolfgang Nolting's 'Analytical Mechanics', the concept of 'generalized potential' is discussed:

For non-conservative systems, but with holonomic constraints, instead of that, the starting point must be :
$$
\frac{d}{d t} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}_j}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_j}=Q_j, \quad j=1,2, \ldots, S .
$$
However, we come to formally unchanged Lagrange equations for the so-called Generalized potentials
$$
U=U\left(q_1, \ldots, q_S, \dot{q}_1, \ldots, \dot{q}_S, t\right)
$$
if the generalized forces $Q_j$ are derivable from $U$ by:
$$
Q_j=\frac{d}{d t} \frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot{q}_j}-\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_j}, \quad j=1,2, \ldots, S .
$$
The first term on the right-hand side is new compared to the case of a conservative system. For the
Generalized Lagrangian function
$$
L=T-U
$$

Suppose we have the equation $\frac{d}{d t} \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}_j}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_j}=Q_j$, where $j=1,2, \ldots, S$, and $T$ is explicitly given, say, as a simple quadratic equation. Since the equation involving the generalized potential $U$ is consistent with it, expressed as $\frac{d}{d t} \frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot{q}_j}-\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_j}$ for $j=1,2, \ldots, S$, can I directly consider $T$ as $U$ by this method to determine $U$? Or  $T$ and  $U$  differ by a constant. Would such a definition of $U$ not cause confusion?

Comments to the question (v2):

The generalized velocity-dependent potential $U$ exists in many important cases, but does not exist for e.g. dissipative forces, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.

In a nutshell, the Lagrange equations ("EOMs") equate kinematics ("acceleration") with dynamics ("forces").

The kinetic term $T$ and the dynamic term $U$ should not be conflated. Doing so may turn a useful non-trivial EOM into a useless trivial identity.



Your third point made me understand that these two are not the same type of quantities, which reminded me of a question someone mentioned before: since $\hat{H}\Psi~=~i\hbar \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t} $,Why can't $ i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ be considered the Hamiltonian operator?I think I have the same misunderstanding as that person
